# How to print the entire row of table and remove the jQuery client-side pagination?

Tags: jquery, printing, pagination

I am using this pagination plugins, you can find it [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Client-side-HTML-Table-Pagination-Plugin-with-jQuery-Paging.html)

And i want to print the whole table using print div javascript

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $.widget("zpd.paging", {
            options: {
                limit: 5,
                rowDisplayStyle: 'block',
                activePage: 0,
                rows: []
            },
            _create: function() {
                var rows = $("tbody", this.element).children();
                this.options.rows = rows;
                this.options.rowDisplayStyle = rows.css('display');
                var nav = this._getNavBar();
                this.element.after(nav);
                this.showPage(0);
            },
            _getNavBar: function() {
                var rows = this.options.rows;
                var nav = $('<div>', {class: 'paging-nav'});
                for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(rows.length / this.options.limit); i++) {
                    this._on($('<a>', {
                        href: '#',
                        text: (i + 1),
                        "data-page": (i)
                    }).appendTo(nav),
                            {click: "pageClickHandler"});
                }
                //create previous link
                this._on($('<a>', {
                    href: '#',
                    text: '<<',
                    "data-direction": -1
                }).prependTo(nav),
                        {click: "pageStepHandler"});
                //create next link
                this._on($('<a>', {
                    href: '#',
                    text: '>>',
                    "data-direction": +1
                }).appendTo(nav),
                        {click: "pageStepHandler"});
                return nav;
            },
            showPage: function(pageNum) {
                var num = pageNum * 1; //it has to be numeric
                this.options.activePage = num;
                var rows = this.options.rows;
                var limit = this.options.limit;
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (i >= limit * num && i < limit * (num + 1)) {
                        $(rows[i]).css('display', this.options.rowDisplayStyle);
                    } else {
                        $(rows[i]).css('display', 'none');
                    }
                }
            },
            pageClickHandler: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(event.target).siblings().attr('class', "");
                $(event.target).attr('class', "selected-page");
                var pageNum = $(event.target).attr('data-page');
                this.showPage(pageNum);
            },
            pageStepHandler: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //get the direction and ensure it's numeric
                var dir = $(event.target).attr('data-direction') * 1;
                var pageNum = this.options.activePage + dir;
                //if we're in limit, trigger the requested pages link
                if (pageNum >= 0 && pageNum < this.options.rows.length) {
                    $("a[data-page=" + pageNum + "]", $(event.target).parent()).click();
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
   $('#showdata').paging({
        limit: 10,
        rowDisplayStyle: 'block',
        activePage: 0,
        rows: []
});

    $('#cetak').click(function () {
        var contents = $(".mod").html();
        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print">@page{size:landscape;}</style><html><head><title>Cetak Lapora</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" > table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style>');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="cetak"><i  class="fa fa-print"></i> <b>Cetak</b></button>
<div class="mod">
    <table width="100%" id="showdata" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">No</td>
          <td rowspan="2" >Nomor /Tanggal LHP</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Nomor Obrik/Judul Laporan</td>
          <td colspan="2">Temuan(TP)</td>
          <td colspan="2">Tindak lanjut(TPL)</td>
          <td colspan="2">SALDO(TPB)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>#Kej</td>
          <td>Nilai Rp.</td>
          <td>#Kej</td>
          <td>Nilai Rp.</td>
          <td>#Kej</td>
          <td>NIlai Rp</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>SKHU-LT10<br>2017-08-28 </td>
            <td>INi adalah Contoh Judul</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>SKHU-LT10<br>2017-08-28 </td>
            <td>INi adalah Contoh Judul</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>SKHU-LT10<br>2017-08-28 </td>
            <td>INi adalah Contoh Judul</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>KUL-IO<br>2017-09-20 </td>
            <td>Penambahan Data Sekunder Bl blabla</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>19-00001-1991<br>2017-09-27 </td>
            <td>Penambahan Data Sekuler </td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Oke <br>2017-09-18 </td>
            <td>Penambahan Bahan</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>VG-PW-20/T3<br>2015-01-01 </td>
            <td>Laporan Dana Desa (DD) </td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>GT-20<br>2017-01-01 </td>
            <td>Pengertian dan Contoh Laporan Keuangan</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>PWT-20/10/40T90<br>2017-09-05 </td>
            <td>Akuntansi dan Laporan Keuangan</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>SKTU-LK01<br>2017-09-05 </td>
            <td>Ekonomi Akuntansi: ANALISIS LAPORAN KEUANGAN</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>PKL-WT/T60/10<br>2017-09-09 </td>
            <td>Laporan Keuangan Konsolidasian</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>PW-250/100/H201<br>2017-09-05 </td>
            <td>Laporan Dana Desa (DD)  Dengan Deksipisi Contoh</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>PW/24-20<br>2017-10-24 </td>
            <td>Ini adalah judul laporan</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          </tr>
            </tbody>
       
    
        </table>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

While my pagination is still active

**JS pagination**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#showdata').paging({
        limit: 10,
        rowDisplayStyle: 'block',
        activePage: 0,
        rows: []
});
})
```

When i am trying to print the whole table, it just print 10 rows while it has 13 rows or it just print the page 1, while it had 3 pages that each page contain 10 rows. What's wrong with my code ? does anyone here have tried this plugins before ?

**JS print**

```
$(function () {
    $('#cetak').click(function () {
        var contents = $(".mod").html();
        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print">@page{size:landscape;}</style><html><head><title>Cetak Lapora</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');
        frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" > table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style>');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

This is what i got when i tried to print. It just print the first page. What i want is it  will print the entire table without pagination

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Replace this syntax

```
frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" > table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style>');
```

To

```
frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css" >table > tbody > tr{ display: table-row!important} .paging-nav{display:none;}table { border-collapse: collapse; }.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th { border: 1px solid #e9ecef; }.table td, .table th { padding: .75rem; vertical-align: top;} table tr td {font-size:12px;}table > thead > tr >th , table> tbody > tr > td {font-size:10px}  #dontprint{display:none} .dontshow{display:display} </style>');
```

What's change is the `.paging-nav` and `table` css

```
"table > tbody > tr{ display: table-row!important} .paging-nav{display:none;}"
```

Below is a style for table border and padding

```
 table{ border-collapse: collapse; }
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th { border: 1px solid #e9ecef; }
.table td, .table th { padding: .75rem; vertical-align: top;}
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pksLv9tk/24/)**

Comment: when i tried it  once, it's work.. but when i am trying to tried the second times, it give me blank page...

Comment: can you explain that ?

Comment: hey first page 10 rows style is <tr style="display: table-row"> next 11,12 and 13 rows is <tr style="display: none"> i mean second page, then when you click print button it ill only print 10 rows so i set overall tbody > tr {display: table-row;} now overall tbody tr "display: table-row"

Comment: i just commnet this line in script its working fine for me  frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">');

Comment: understandable sir (y)